# Transit Without Visa through Heathrow for travel from Canada - is it still valid during COVID?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, lhr, twov

I am a Canadian permanent resident with Indian passport. I will be traveling on BA flight from Toronto to Mumbai on a single ticket which has a layover of 23 hours in London. This means I would have to leave Heathrow.

I tweeted Heathrow Airport and asked them about the quarantine mandate (Canada is not on the exempt list) and they said I am exempt from the 14 day quarantine as long as I quarantine for my entire stay in London (just a night) and travel only from Heathrow to hotel and hotel back to Heathrow to take the connecting flight.

However, just to be sure, I wanted to check if anyone has been through a similar situation in recent times and if they had any trouble at the UK border?

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question. There are a few points here:

1. TWOV will still be allowed after I checked with Heathrow Airport. COVID doesn't affect that.
2. BA however does not let you board the flight from India to Canada since BA is meant only for repatriation to UK (at least till Nov 30th until when commercial international flights are suspended in India). Similarly, for instance, Lufthansa is meant for repatriation between India and Germany, United for the US. For travel to Canada as a Canadian PR from India, the air bubble agreement by Indian government with Canada states that I can only take Indian carriers (Air India) or Air Canada.
3. Similarly, the air bubble agreement between different countries only allows Indian carriers or one of the country's carriers (examples above).